# How to calculate confidence interval of a data?

Tags: repeated-measures

How to calculate 95% CI data for the following 11 readings:

```
102.61 100.31 107.04 95.00 105.61 97.75 107.76 96.56 92.90 96.98 102.03
```

Average = 100.41, 
Std. dev. = 5.017

Comment: Check wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Comment: You don't make CI's for data. If you want a CI for the *mean* you should say that. If you want a PI, or a tolerance interval (which are arguably intervals for 'data'), then say that. If you want a CI for some other quantity, be specific.

Comment: I thank all of you @Salvador Dali ,@Matt Krause And Glen_b for your response .To be frankly with you I Have no clue about how to phrase the question nor to solve it.I was requested to find the 95% CI of series of tests to a known reference which is 100 PPM,my results are shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the CI with the following formula: $\textrm{CI} = \textrm{mean}(\textrm{data}) \pm Z(a/2) \frac{std}{ \sqrt{n} }$

- mean(data) is already known to you,
- $Z(a/2)$ can be found from a table, where $a = 0.95$. For your particular case it will be $1.96$
- standard deviation is also given
- $n$ is the number of elements in your data

Comment: can someone please show me how to create nice formulas here? Would be very thankful.

Comment: Here you go (for the formulas) http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: For a sample size this small, I'd use a t-based interval.